# Bixby runtime version 3

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

When using the latest version of Bixby Studio (7.11.0-r20b.14375), I am setting `runtime-version (2)` for my capsule and getting the following warning:

```
INFO A newer version is available: runtime-version(3)
```

But when I go to the Bixby Developers documentation for runtime-version I don't see any documentation on version 3, only on version 1 and 2: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/capsule.runtime-version

Can anybody clarify what is the difference between runtime version 2 and runtime version 3?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I am working with DOC team to see if we can get the updated DOC online. I will post updates later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs have been updated to show the latest runtime-version (3): https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/capsule.runtime-version